# Como pegar cada valor de um objecto jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O meu array de resultado :

```
 {
   "status": "accept",
   "info": "",
   "message": {
     "row": {
       "1": {
         "id": "1677",
         "state": "AC",
         "stateid": null,
         "address": "RUA   MARIA LUCIOLA DA SILVA",
         "addressinfo": null,
         "cityid": null,
         "neighborhoodid": null,
         "city": "RIO BRANCO",
         "neighborhood": " VILA DA AMIZADE",
         "addressnumber": null
       }
     },
     "rows": []
   }
 }
```

quero pegar por exemplo: id:1677

Comment: `objeto.message.row[1].id` É isto que você quer?

Comment: ^ . Também não confunda jQuery com uma linguagem de programação. jQuery é só uma library.

Comment: Obrigado, foi isso que eu queria...

Comment: Esse JSON foi obtido por uma requisição Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura é similar ao array do PHP:

```
var result = {
       "status": "accept",
       "info": "",
       "message": {
         "row": {
           "1": {
             "id": "1677",
             "state": "AC",
             "stateid": null,
             "address": "RUA   MARIA LUCIOLA DA SILVA",
             "addressinfo": null,
             "cityid": null,
             "neighborhoodid": null,
             "city": "RIO BRANCO",
             "neighborhood": " VILA DA AMIZADE",
             "addressnumber": null
           }
         },
         "rows": []
       }
     }
```

Para pegar a **id** de: message -> row -> 1: `result.message.row[1].id` ou `result['message']['row'][1]['id']`

Para pegar o status: `result.status`
Para pegar a info: `result.info`
Para pegar a rows: `result.message.rows`